# xmlhttprequest CORS won't allow me to access my api

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors, cgi

Hy i realy have some issues with CORS i have 2 webservers running one is hosting the actuall page and the other is running some python cgi skripts.
The page where my actuall webpage is on responses with this header:

**General**

```
Request URL:http://10.208.71.10/de/svg/00000002.svg?base=undefined
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:10.208.71.10:80
```

**Response Headers:**

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: WebMI SDK/0.9.0
Date: Tue, 26 Jan 2016 21:33:18 GMT
Connection: Keep-Alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
Content-Length: 2378608
Content-Type: image/svg+xml
Last-Modified: Tue, 26 Jan 2016 21:13:28 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

**Query String Parameter:**

```
base=undefined
```

this page contains this small piece of code:

```
var getJSON = function(url, successHandler, errorHandler) {
  var xhr = typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined'
    ? new XMLHttpRequest()
    : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  xhr.open('get', url, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('origin', "http://10.208.65.216*");
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var status;
    var data;
    // https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-xmlhttprequest-readystate
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) { // `DONE`
      status = xhr.status;
      if (status == 200) {
        data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        successHandler && successHandler(data);
      } else {
        errorHandler && errorHandler(status);
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
};
```

When i call getJSON("http://10.208.65.216:8082/cgi/3daxis.py", function(d) {...}, function(s) {...});
The Browser Rejects it with CORS error.

My Second webserver running the cgi script will answer like this (If the browser would be happy with it :S):

**General**

```
Request URL:http://10.208.65.216:8082/cgi/3daxis.py
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 Script output follows
Remote Address:10.208.65.216:8082
```

**Response Headers**

```
HTTP/1.0 200 Script output follows
Server: SimpleHTTP/0.6 Python/2.7.3
Date: Tue, 26 Jan 2016 19:35:35 GMT
Content-type: text/plain
Content-Location: 3daxis.py
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
```

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Access-Control-Allow-Methods` cannot have the value `*`. I recommend studying the [CORS protocol](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-cors-protocol).

Comment: Hy thank for the link. I found the Problem. It wasn't realy the Header, the Browser send a Head Request wich din't get answered corectly :)